# What is the difference between "Mitteilung" and "Benachrichtigung"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I have searched in my dictionary to notice any difference but none appears.
The meaning of both is "notification".

Is it that "Mitteilung" may be a notification on phone(when a message or notification is received) and "Benachrichtigung" an official notification(about a request)?

Comment: *Die Benachrichtigung* focuses on the action of having someone take notice, while *die Mitteilung* focuses on the content of the message.

Comment: Is there any more precise **context** other than *"on the phone"* or *"official"* for using *notification*? We will not be able to choose the appropriate term for you without knowing what it was meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily a matter of *formality*. "Mitteilung" is rarely used in normal speech because it's an abstract word; you're more likely to talk about a concrete "Brief", "Anruf", "Text", "Aushang", "Anzeige" etc.

"Mitteilung" is only used when you talk about *any* possible kind of notification - for instance, a law might mandate informing the public about something but leave the channel unspecified. This makes "Mitteilung" rather formal.

"Benachrichtigung" is *very* formal - it's used almost *only* in *Amtsdeutsch* (officialese).

Answer (score 1):

We call letters from the authorities rather »amtliche Mitteilung / Bescheid« than »amtliche Benachrichtigung«. They often come unexpectedly and are mostly bad news. E. g.:

> Sie sind zu schnell gefahren.
>   *(You drove too fast.)*
>
> Sie müssen Steuern nachzahlen.
>   *(You have to pay more taxes.)*
>
> Ihr Haftantritt wurde vorverlegt auf den 1. Mai.
>   *(Your imprisonment was brought forward to the 1st of May.)*
>
> In Kalenderwoche 42 wird Ihre Straße aufgerissen.
>   *(In calendar week 42 your street is torn up.)*

A »Benachrichtigung« is more often one of those:

> - private
> - expected or desired / pre-ordered
> - alert-like

with possible content:

> - a person has reached a location
> - calendar app reminds of a date
> - a forum thread has a new answer or an answer has a new comment
> - ...

Comment: Don't you think the use of one or the other depends very much on the context that we unfortunately do not know?

Comment: @Takkat: Je genauer gefragt wird, umso genauer kann man antworten. Es geht aber auch so.

Comment: *Auch so* ist kaum mehr wert als ein Wörterbucheintrag und genau [das wollten wir eigentlich vermeiden](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the occurence of *Mitteilung* vs. *Benachrichtigung* on translating notification by phone or from official sources.

[image]<sup>[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams)</sup>

Still, depending on the context, the content or nature of that notification they are not 100% synonym. We will prefer one over the other but for official notifications *Bescheid* is more common.